# Please help solve flutter app get this problem

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting the following error while trying to build run the app in debug mode on android.

Looks like there is an issue with the shared preferences package launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...

```
   C:\Users\rootx\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:9: warning: [deprecation] AsyncTask in android.os has been deprecated
            import android.os.AsyncTask;
C:\Users\rootx\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:121: warning: [deprecation] AsyncTask in android.os has been deprecated
                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {           C:\Users\rootx\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:121: warning: [deprecation] AsyncTask() in AsyncTask has been deprecated
                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
                ^
            
            C:\Users\rootx\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:123: warning: [deprecation] doInBackground(Params...) in AsyncTask has been deprecated
                  protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                                    ^
              where Params,Result are type-variables:
                Params extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
                Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
            C:\Users\rootx\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:121: warning: [deprecation] AsyncTask() in AsyncTask has been deprecated
                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {                                                                        C:\Users\rootx\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:128: warning: [deprecation] onPostExecute(Result) in AsyncTask has been deprecated
                  protected void onPostExecute(Boolean value) {
                                 ^
              where Result is a type-variable:
                Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask         C:\Users\rootx\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:131: warning: [deprecation] execute(Params...) in AsyncTask has been deprecated
                }.execute();
                 ^
              where Params,Progress,Result are type-variables:
                Params extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
                Progress extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
                Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
            7 warnings
           
            I/flutter_petcar( 8034): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
            I/flutter_petcar( 8034): Unquickening 12 vdex files!
            W/flutter_petcar( 8034): Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your shared preferences plugin to the latest version which is `shared_preferences: ^2.0.8`,

then `flutter clean` and
 `flutter run` again.

Comment: the share preferences are solve , now got another error

Comment: @xiaohao please add another question for that specific error, if I change the answer will not help others.

Comment: @xiaohao you need to accept this answer if it solved your original problem, don't add follow up question

Comment: ok thank for this solution